# CPU Timeout Limit reached

Tags: apex, batch, cpulimit

I know this is vague but to be honest I don't know what else to do other than ask here.

We have various Apex classes which used to work without any problems but now frequently fail with a Limits CPU Timeout exception. I know the limits have not changed, so logically, the only other possibility is that execution takes longer. But the classes have not been changed, neither has the data. So, I'm forced to assume that something in salesforce has changed and the execution is actually slower.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Are you sure that the data amount hasn't been changed? Example: triggers on leads work fine until leads amount increase significantly thorough the years. Or maybe you are processing some related records data that has increased?

Comment: Another guess: number of your processes or flows has increased and DML operations take much longer that they did.

Comment: The first thing I'd look at here is the analysis view in the developer console (when viewing a log: Debug -> Switch Perspective -> Analysis). Sure, it won't tell you how your code _used_ to perform, but it can help narrow down problem areas. Second thing I'd look at is to see if there are any new declarative things that have been added (workflow rules with field updates, Process Builder, Flows).

Comment: Multiple things can impact CPU time -- for example, enabled debug logs make execution slower, or sometimes SF does not cut the transaction if it runs for 11-15 seconds. If things take to run up to 70-90% to CPU at normal use, it is wise to do research about how to reduce logic done in one transaction. Anyway, hard to advice anything without knowing the context/data set/ actual code

Comment: I agree with @mariiaillarionova. In our experience this sort of change is typically due to addition of automation (flows etc.). These are not very CPU efficient (though are improving with time).

Answer (score 4):

This is a complicated topic, but generally speaking, Apex code has gotten faster in recent years. There are non-code reasons why you might now be having problems. It could be that your code was already borderline over the limit (say, an average of 12 seconds), and the system has adjusted your flexible CPU time limit downwards as a result. Alternatively, it could be that your code was already borderline over the limit and someone added a new Flow, or other non-code related changes. Without some debug logs, it'd be hard to tell, but therein lies the catch: debugging inherently increases the CPU time, which might trick you in to thinking the problem is somewhere different than it actually is.

I recommend that you set up a Profiling Debug Level. Under this proposal, you set PROFILING to FINEST, and set all other attributes to NONE. This will at least provide hints as to which methods are taking the most time, which you can then further test by writing unit tests, execute anonymous scripts, and so on, to narrow down the culprit. You could also write up some "canary" assertions in your unit tests avoid this sort of thing happening in the future. Such assertions would look like: `System.assert(Limits.getCpuTime() < 9000, 'CPU time is over 9000!')` *(sorry, couldn't resist)* You'll need to definitely read some profiling logs to figure out where the problem is.